# mapping naked domain (www.domain.com) to static website which is saved in s3

Tags: domains, amazon-s3, godaddy

I am developing an web application, I recently purchased the domain from godaddy.com and the domain is use google apps, for email, calendar docs and other services as well.
Now I just need to show that" my site is under construction" I have a static page which is put on S3 now I need to map "www.mydomain.com" to that static page which is stored on s3. I am kinda of newbie/novice to this so kindly help me.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can think of is point an A record in your DNS to the elastic IP from AWS. This has the advantage that it never actually hits your host - it goes straight from the DNS to AWS, so it should be faster as well.

Answer (score 2):

Three simple steps for this:

1. Your S3 bucket must be named the same as your desired subdomain: "www.domain.com".
2. You need to setup a CNAME record to in your DNS to point your subdomain to the S3 bucket:
          CNAME  www.domain.com  ->  www.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com
3. You need to make you splash page the "index document" for the bucket so that it will open by default. (See: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?IndexDocumentSupport.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm totally following, but you could do one of two things as a hack I think...

1) If you know the correct URL you could redirect from your domain to the other URL (this may be bad for traffic later though when your domain rolls to the correct "live" one)

2) You could set up a page on the new domain with a big iFrame that loads the other URL. The down side here is all the sub pages will not have updated URLs in the browser...

This may be closer to the solution you're looking for though...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570890/amazon-s3-url-rewrite